# VS code and Anaconda - requiring full path to access files and creating them (Pyhton)

Tags: python, path, anaconda

I got this issue that every time that I'll export a .csv or read one, I need to writhe the full path to the folder, when I only wanted to create or read a file that is in the folder of the project. I don't think is related to Pandas cause when I try with other modules, the same thing happens.

For example, my code is in the "Simulator v1.6" folder, and I just want to export a .csv to this folder, but when I execute:

```
df.to_csv("listofcoord.csv")
```

Nothing happens, the file is only created when I write the full path:

```
df.to_csv('C:\\Users\\Kido\\OneDrive\\Documents\\01.Polish Editor\\Code_polisheditor\\SIMULATOR\\Simulator v1.6\\listofcoord.csv')
```

I wonder if is something to do with using Anaconda environment in VScode

Comment: If you're on Windows, it will probably write the file to the "current working directory," or to some other default location.  Do a search of your disk - I suspect the files have been written somewhere.  You have to find out where they are, and why they are being put there.

Comment: Just found it, you are right, thanks